# How do I embed an applet in my JSP?

Tags: jsp, applet

OK so I have the following structure:

Web Pages > Administrator > test.jsp

In this JSP I have the following code:

```
 <jsp:plugin type="applet" code="appletexample/AppletExample.class"width="400" height="400"> 
<jsp:fallback> <p>Unable to load applet</p>
</jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>
```

My applet is located in Source Packages > appletexample > AppletExample.java

The problem is I get a classnotfound exception when I run the jsp page and the applet isn't shown.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the applet is to be created as a separate Java project and to be exported in flavor of a JAR file into the public web content of the webapp project. You'd just have to reference the physical JAR archive in the `codebase` attribute and reference the fully qualified name in the `code` attribute. The below example assumes that the `yourapplet.jar` is in the same folder as the current JSP file.

Structure:

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |    `-- MANIFEST.MF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- page.jsp
 `-- yourapplet.jar
```

JSP:

```html
 <jsp:plugin type="applet" codebase="yourapplet.jar" code="appletexample.AppletExample" width="400" height="400">
```

However, when not bundling the applet as a JAR file and fiddling with loose `.class` files, then you need to prepare a folder structure in the public web content folder matching the desired package structure and put the compiled class files in there. Assuming that there's only one class file (i.e. there are no inner/nested classes in the main applet class!), then here's how you'd need to structure and reference it:

Structure:

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |    `-- MANIFEST.MF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- appletexample
 |    `-- AppletExample.class
 `-- page.jsp
```

JSP:

```html
 <jsp:plugin type="applet" codebase="." code="appletexample.AppletExample" width="400" height="400">
```

Comment: I had an issue here that unless I used `archive` instead of `codebase` when packaged in a .jar, it would give a class not found exception. Changing it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

–
Using
jsp:include
to include pages at request time
•
**<%@ include file="..." %>**

–
Using
<%@ include ... %>
(the include directive)
to include files at page translation time
•

Usage
–
Understanding why
jsp:include
is usually better than
the include directive

•
Applets
–
Using
jsp:plugin
to include applets for the Java
Plug-in (rare!)